# How to separate div to display on the same line?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to separate `find an event` and `post an event`and put them on the same line below `Events`

Html:

```
<div class="lasvegas">
Events</div>
<div class="findanevent"> </div>
<div class="event_wrapper"><a href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an- 
event/"><span id="findanevent" class="event">Find an Event</span>. 
</a>
<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/"><span id="postanevent" 
class="event">Post an Event</span></a></div>
```

Page:https://adsler.co.uk/events/

Tried css `.events {display: block;}` didn't work

This worked in mobile but how to replicate in desktop?

`.event {float :right;} .findanevent br {display: none;}`

Comment: Add a ```display: inline-block;``` to ```.event``` class and remove ```<br>``` tag between them.

Comment: Use `display: inline;` I used this with inspect element and fixed as you want.

Comment: @Sky this worked in mobile but how to replicate in desktop? `. event {float :right;} 

.findanevent br {display: none;}`

Comment: @Llazar this worked in mobile but how to replicate in desktop?`. event {float :right;} 

.findanevent br {display: none;}`

Comment: Remove new line between **a** tags, this will remove ```<br>``` tag. And right css is ```.event_wrapper a {display: inline-block;}```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.event_wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lasvegas" style="text-align: center">
  Events
</div>
<div class="event_wrapper">
  <div>
    <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-  event/"><span id="findanevent" class="event">Find an Event</span></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/"><span id="postanevent" class="event">Post an Event</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would worl for desktop and mobile?